# Suggestion to vote answers up to help the questioner decide the accepted answer

Tags: discussion

I think any experts who know that the answer is correct should vote it up as a confirmation. For me, it will help me to decide whether I have to accept it as the solution or I have to wait for other answers. If the answer has enough upvotes then I am sure it will be the final solution.

If the experts just read it without giving any comments, how can I as the questioner know it is enough to use it as the solution?

What do you think? Does this policy make sense?

Comment: And the question is not necessarily to be voted up.

Comment: Surely voting up correct/useful answers is the whole idea behind Stack Exchange? I'm not quite sure what you're getting at here - are you asking how we can *encourage* people to up-vote answers?

Comment: Because I noticed that most answers have not enough up vote so I am not confident to use the answer. I think it is not reliable enough. :-) Yes. I need  other people to encourage to up vote answers.

Comment: I sometimes don't know what to do with answers that are accurate but not very much detailed, and in such cases, I tend to do neither upvote nor downvote. Perhaps I should upvote them, I wonder?

Comment: @Yosh If the answer remains at 0, then the question will stay on the Unanswered Questions list, and it will periodically get bumped to the top of the main question list so more people will see it.  That's a good thing, because it means the question is more likely to get a useful answer in the future.  If an answer isn't adequate on its own, even if it's correct, then I would avoid upvoting it.

Comment: Isn't this already what is supposed to happen...??